# CalDAV query with text-match for ANY property?

Tags: caldav

I'd like for a user to enter a search string (for example, "Narnia") and get a list of calendar events where "Narnia" is present in the summary, description, location, or attendee list.

Adding multiple prop-filters seems to return only components that match ALL of the filters (in this example, only events that have "Narnia" in ALL of the properties). Is there a way to specify a query for components matching ANY of the filters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to specify such a filter with the current CalDAV spec.

What you are asking for is described in https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-daboo-caldav-extensions which is currently expired. I doubt that many servers have implemented this feature so want your client to check for its presence:

> Servers advertise support for this extension by including the token
> "calendar-query-extended" in the DAV response header to an OPTIONS
> request on any resource supporting the extended query report.
> Clients MUST check for the presence of that token before using the
> "test" or "match-type" XML attributes.